# How to flatten an array of objects into arrays for each object parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    p1: 1
    p2: 2
  },
  {
    p1: 3
    p2: 4
  }
]
```

I would like to flatten this into an array (maintaining order) for each property on the object:

```
[1, 3] and [2, 4]
```

Preferably these would be stored in a dictionary with the property as the key:

```
{
   p1: [1, 3],
   p2: [2, 4]
}
```

Is there a non brute force method of doing this in javascript? I am already using both jQuery and Underscore.js if those libraries are any help here.

My current plan is to iterate through all of the objects in the array and manually add each property value to its corresponding array. I'm interested to know if there is more interesting way of doing this.

Comment: There is no order to maintain, objects don't have order.

Comment: @adeneo But arrays do and I think the order in question is determined by the order of the objects within the array.

Comment: @muistooshort - but there are objects inside the array above, there's no way to know if `1` comes before `2` as there is no order between those two values, there's no guarantee one would come before the other.

Comment: @adeneo: Nonsense. The `{ p1: 1, p2: 2 }` object appears in the array before the `{ p1: 3, p2: 4 }` object so `1` comes before `3` in the `p1` array and `2` before `4` in the `p2` array. The array that contains the objects specifies the order.

Comment: @muistooshort that is right, actually, good point.

Comment: @muistooshort - but there's no guarantee it will be `{ p1: 1, p2: 2 }`, it could be `{ p2: 2, p1: 1 }`, and the other way in the next object, which gets you `[2, 3], [1, 4]`, there's no reliable way to get `[1, 3], [2, 4]`

Comment: yes, sorry if I was unclear, I would like the order within each property array to be determined by the order of the objects in the original array (as @muistooshort said)

Comment: @adeneo But no one (except you) is talking about the order of the keys in the object. The standard doesn't guarantee any particular order of the keys in an object (beyond saying that if there is an order then it applies everywhere) but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Are all of these objects guaranteed to have the same properties? They will all have both p1 and p2? No p3, p4? None will have only p1 or p2?

Comment: @muistooshort - you and the OP obviously understand the end result here, I'm probably just confused and don't really get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the properties are reliably the same on each object, you can use underscore like this.

```
var keys = _.keys(arr[0]);

var newObj = _.reduce(keys,function(obj,key){
   obj[key] = _.pluck(arr,key)
},{});
//newObj will now be in the requested format
```

If the properties are different on different objects, you'll need to do some additional logic to get the complete list of properties to iterate over.

Comment: Nice little optimization to use pluck there. The only issue would be if the objects had different keys, which, as far as we can tell, they do not.

Comment: Might be more natural to use `reduce` than separate initialization (`var obj = { }`) and iteration (`_.each`) steps.

Comment: in my case, the objects all have the same keys, so this looks excellent

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(acc, x) {
  Object.keys(x).forEach(function(k) {
    acc[k] = (acc[k] || []).concat([x[k]])
  })
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
//^ {
//    p1: [1, 3],
//    p2: [2, 4]
//  }
```

But note that object keys have no order, and the result is up to each  implementation. You may have to sort the resulting arrays if you need a specific order.